# Convert ini.txt to JSON in node.js

Tags: node.js, json, ini, converters

I'm currently facing following problem:

There is an ini.txt for a specific machine pushed into a S3 Bucket and a lambda is triggered then. The **ini.txt** looks like this:

```
1 | test
1sdf | test2
2sdf | abcdefghifsfd
sdfsdfsdf
```

so we have an **id | message** but no delimiter at the and and sometimes the message is so long that it needs two rows.

I need to transform this ini.txt to a **JSON Object**.

I am already able to get the content of the ini as a string in my script.

Do you guys have an idea how to solve that or is there already a node package for that problem?

I appreciate every help.

Thanks!

Comment: Did you make an attempt at it? If so what was the problem? If the ini file is a set of key/value pair separated by a pipe on each line this is just a matter of splitting the content of the file by lines (`content.split('\n'`)) splitting the lines around the pipes (`line.split(' | ')`) and assign the value of each key to a corresponding key in a javascript object (`obj[key] = value`). And finally apply JSON.stringify on the resulting object.

Comment: hey thanks for the quick answer! :) I dont want an exact solution, more a guidance to the right way. It is a set of key values separated with the | but at the end of the line there is no delimiter. So how do I check if the message is over more than one row and where does it end? With a delimiter at the end (for example a semicolon it would be much easier)

Comment: If there are lines, then there are newline ('\n' or '\r\n' depending on the os the file was created in) control character at the end of each line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote code for you:

```js
const { readFileSync } = require('fs')

const data = readFileSync('ini.txt', 'utf8').split(/[\n\r]/)
const result = {}

let prev = {}
let preKey

data.forEach(line => {
    const key = line.split('|')[0]
    const value = line.split('|')[1]
    const _ = {}

    if (!value) {
        prev[preKey] += key
        result[preKey] = prev[preKey]
    } else {
        result[key] = value
    }

    _[key] = value
    prev = _
    preKey = key
})

console.log(JSON.stringify(result))
```

Comment: You could [edit] your answer and include explanation why/how this code solves issue. In theory people come here to learn, not to get a ready copy-paste code

Comment: hey Minwoo, I could solve it with the tips by remix above, but your code looks cleaner and is much less code. Thanks a lot for that!

Comment: @barbsan I was not looking for a solution to copy and paste, I wanted hints about possible packages or guidance how to proceed :)